# Append to text in a microsoft word table

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have a table in MS word as shown below:
[image: screenshot]

I need to amend the second bullet point to append a variable to (title). I can identify the cell and return all of the text however I cannot seem to isolate the individual line that I would like to change.

The code I have so far is:
`

```
import docx

# Varibles
documentname = 'yyyy-mm-dd - 0000 - Releasse Name - Instructions.docx'
title = 'Test release'

# Load document for changes
doc = docx.Document(documentname)

print(doc.tables[1].cell(2,0).text)
```

`

I can repleace text based on the string, however I lose the bullet points and this does not seem to the best solution.

Any help will be gretly recieved.

Thank you

`

```
import docx

# Varibles
documentname = 'yyyy-mm-dd - 0000 - Releasse Name - Instructions.docx'
title = 'Test release'

# Load document for changes
doc = docx.Document(documentname)

releasenote = doc.tables[1].cell(2,0).text

releasenotechanged = releasenote.replace("Set the value of the deployment directory package variable to","Set the value of the deployment directory package variable to " + title)
doc.tables[1].cell(2,0).text = releasenotechanged

#Save file after all updates
doc.save (documentname)
```

`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to access the cell's paragraphs in order to achieve something like that.

an example api use-case of that would be:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document()

t = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=1)
t.style = 'Table Grid'

t.cell(1, 0).add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)
t.cell(1, 0).add_paragraph(
    '2nd item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)

t.cell(1, 0).add_paragraph(
    '3rd item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)

# index of para is 2, because there's always 1 empty paragraph per each cell by default
# therefore we have 4 paras in that cell, an empty one and the three new ones
t.cell(1, 0).paragraphs[2].text += ' ***amending 2nd item in the list***'

doc.save('t1.docx')
```

therefore in your case, you can amend the list bullet like this:

```
doc.tables[1].cell(2,0).paragraphs[3].text += f' {title}'
# assuming that 3rd para is `Set the value of the deployment...`
```